# .NET MAUI set focus to control into ControlTemplate

Tags: xaml, .net-maui

I have this ControlTemplate (two controls on it):

```
<Style TargetType="controls:QuickSearch">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                    <Entry
                        x:Name="EntryFilter"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Filter}"
                        Completed="Entry_Completed"
                        behaviors:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference LstResults}"
                        Focused="Entry_Focused"
                        ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                        Placeholder="{TemplateBinding PlaceHolder,Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <Entry.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger Event="Completed">

                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Entry.Triggers>
                    </Entry>
                    <ListView
                        x:Name="LstResults"
                        Margin="5"
                        Background="{DynamicResource PN_ColorFondoPrimario}"
                        ZIndex="999"
                        ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Results}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
                        IsVisible="{TemplateBinding PerforminigSearch}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding DisplayField}" Margin="9"/>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Triggers>

                        </ListView.Triggers>
                    </ListView>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <-- MAUI don't allow to set triggers here -->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>


                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <--  ======================================= -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I want to set the focus into `EntryFilter` when my control template receives focus. I was trying with a trigger, but MAUI doesn't allow me to put some triggers into the `<ControlTemplate>` tag.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:QuickSearch">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="EntryFilter" Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    . . . .
    . . . .
</Style>
```

I tried with MAUI toolkit, but where should I put `SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior`?

Comment: Add to question the line of xaml that you cannot enter.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Some WPF samples allow  ´<ControlTemplate.Triggers>´ !!Code UPDATED!!

Comment: `ControlTemplate` is not a visual element in Maui. Can you put the triggers on `VerticalStackLayout`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve It means Is VerticalStackLayout the element that receives the Focus ?